# how to use with and inner join in Sql server query?

Tags: inner-join

Why this query must be incorrect ? :

```
with a as 
(
  select * 
  from justification_game_publisher 
  inner join justifications 
  on justifications.id = justification_id 
  where game_id=1594
) 
select * 
from games_publisher_class 
inner join a  
on a.game_id = games_publisher_class.game_id 
and a.publisher_id = games_publisher_class.publisher_id
```

sql server says :

> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 2: Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an
>   xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous
>   statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: i just put a ; before with statement and it runs correctly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have additional sql expression before.
Try

```
;with a as (....
```

instead of

```
with a as (....
```

I hope this should help :)